# slide in function android studio

Tags: android, arrays, swift, function

I'm trying to do a similar function in android studio but I'm having trouble getting it. How do I?
I've already got it in swift and it works well.
Every time I click on the next button I want new words coming from the left side to the middle/center.
Here is how it looks like in swift.

```
    func slideInLabel() {
    labelOutlet.center = CGPoint(x: labelOutlet.center.x - 500, y: labelOutlet.center.y)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.40) {
        self.labelOutlet.center = CGPoint(x: self.labelOutlet.center.x + 500, y: self.labelOutlet.center.y)
    }
}
```

this is how it looks
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwyE6.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `textView` is your textView:

```
textView.setText("new text");
textView.setTranslationX(-textView.getRight());
textView.animate().translationX(0.0f);
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you!